# How to move Controls Like Grid or Stack panels as Carouse on click of buttonl in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-2.0

I have one popup. In that popup i have three steps.
All data for that three steps are in one XAML page in three different grids . i want to move that three grid one by one on click of Next button with anymation.
How can i do it with silverlight 3.0

Answer (score 0):

In your button handlers, expand and collapse the named grids using the Visibility property of each.

Page One: GridOne's Visibility="Visible", the other grids are collapsed. In the button handler, set the Visibility to Collapsed, and Visible to GridTwo.